# Where should I put urls in an AJAX based web project?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am on my way to some web development at the moment. There I have a set of views (different versions of the site the user will be able to see). Many of those allow some interaction that is JS/Ajax based. This is just the context of this question:

**Where can I put the request URLs of the various ajax requests?**

I know this seems a little stupid this question thus let me explain a bit. I assume jQuery but this question is basically not strictly related to it. I will try to give very minimalistic snippets to see the idea, these are of course not 1:1 correct/finished/good.

Typically such a site has not only one single type of request but a whole bunch of these. Think of a site where the user sees his personal data like name, mail, address, phone etc. On clicking on one such entry, a minimal form should be displayed to allow modification of the entry. Of course you need minor changes in the replacements (e.g. distinguish between change name and change phone).

First approach was to write ajax code for each and every possible entry separately in a JS file. I mean that each entry gets its own html id and I just replace the content of the element with the named id with the new content. I write code for each id explicitly in JS causing quite some redundancy in code (although a well designed set of functions will help here):

```
$("#name").click(function(){ /* replace #name, hardcode url */});
$("#phone").click(function(){ /* replace #phone, hardcode url */});
```

One other way was to put some `<a>` tag with the `href` set to the url of the AJAX request. Then the developer can define some classes that need to follow a defined and fixed scheme. The JS code gets smaller in size as only a single event must be registered and I need to follow the convention throughout the site.

```html
<div class='foo'>... <a href="ajax.php?first" class="ajax"></div>
<div class='foo'>... <a href="ajax.php?second" class="ajax"></div>
```

and the simplified JS:

```
$(".foo a.ajax").click(function(ev){ /* do something and use source of ev to fetch the url */ });
```

This second method could be done even worse if you did put the url in any html tag and hide it from the user (scary).

Ideally one should write the page such, that all interaction that is AJAX-enabled should be doable with JS disabled as well. Thus I think the way of putting the urls in `<a>` tags is not good. However I think hardcoding them is also not ideal.

So did I miss a useful/typical part of how one can do this? is there even some consesus where such data can be located best?

Answer (score 1):

If your website is big enough, you should seperate your urls based on modules such as banking, finance, user etc. But if you do not have that much urls, you can store all of them in a single javascript file.

You should store BASE url in a single javascript file with all of should import it(in case of your domain changes or development to production mode).

```
//base_url.js
var BASE_URL_PROD = "www......com"; // production server url
var BASE_URL_DEV = "localhost:3000"; // local server url
var BASE_URL = BASE_URL_DEV; // change this if you are on dev or prod mode.

// urls.js
var FETCH_USER = BASE_URL + "/user/fetch";
var SAVE_USER = BASE_URL + "/user/save";

// in some javascript class
$("#clickMe").ajax({url: FETCH_USER} ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question here is: do you want to offer a way to access the information, if javascript is turned off or not loaded yet?

You already answered yourself: If javascript is disabled or not loaded yet, the user will directly go to the given url.

If you want to offer a none-javascript way, change your controller and check for ajax request or just use the javascript way, like Abdullah described already.